# 301 for urls indexed by google containing /index.php/*

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect an old url indexed by google to a new one using 301

I need an example of Rewrite rules for the following 301? `http://www .example.com/index.php/ * / */ *` (`*` being wildcards) to the following `http://www.example.com/*/*/*`

So that when users click the old url indexed by google with the `index.php` they are redirected to the new url without `index.php`.

Any ideas?

best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/(.*)$ /$1
```

Or using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, note that if you have rewrite rules that rewrite requests to point **to** index.php, you're going to get a redirect loop. So you'll need to add a condition to the rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^/index.php
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This ensures that the *actual request* is for a `index.php` and not an internally re-written URI.

Comment: I've tried your solution but I'm still having a problem. I think the RedirectMatch is going to be the solution im looking for however when I added to my htaccess, when I access the url `../index.php/music/2222/playlisttitle` I get `../music/2222/playlisttitle?rewrite=2` 

url `../music/2222/playlisttitle` is functioning properly, still need to get rid of that `?rewrite=2` at  end of url

I have a re-write rule that gets rid of index.php that uese the ?rewrite=2 query as follows `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.php

  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=2 [L,QSA]`

Comment: You want the redirect to remove `rewrite=2` from the query string? RedirectMatch won't match against the query string.

Comment: Its looking like it worked out, I simply removed ?rewrite=2 from my existing rule. It looks like everything is working properly at this point. Thank you!!